# Testing services from $resource using factory with Karma

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, angular-resource

I'm new to karma and I'm trying to run tests in order to check if my factories are set to the proper value returned by the API.

apiServices.js :

```
'use strict';

angular.module('balrogApp.services', ['balrogApp.config'])
  .factory('Requests', ['$resource', 'balrogConfig', function($resource, balrogConfig) {
    return $resource(balrogConfig.backend + '/requests/:id', {id: '@id'});
  }])
  .factory('Projects', ['$resource', 'balrogConfig', function($resource, balrogConfig) {
    return $resource(balrogConfig.backend + '/projects/:id', {id: '@id'}, {'update': { method:'PUT' }});
  }])
  .factory('Users', ['$resource', 'balrogConfig', function($resource, balrogConfig) {
    return $resource(balrogConfig.backend + '/users/:id', {id: '@id'});
  }]);
```

config.js :

```
'use strict';

angular.module('balrogApp.config', [])
  .constant('balrogConfig', {
    'backend': 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/catalog'
  });
```

Now, I've been through a few articles about $resource and karma but I didn't really get how to set up the unit tests for my case.

Here is my test file : (edited after @Freezystem answer)

```
describe("Services test", function () {
  var Requests, Projects, Users;

  beforeEach(function () {
    angular.mock.module("balrogApp.services");
    angular.mock.inject(function (_Requests_, _Projects_, _Users_) {
      Requests = _Requests_;
      Projects = _Projects_;
      Users = _Users_
    });
  });

  it("API factories must be defined", function () {
    expect(Requests).toBeDefined();
    expect(Projects).toBeDefined();
    expect(Users).toBeDefined();
  });
});
```

I also tried a few things with $httpBackend but couldn't make it neither.

How to make this work in order to know if the services are working.

Also, how to check if the services are returning the expected response from the API ?

**Edit :** Adding karma.conf.js :

```
// Karma configuration
// Generated on Tue Nov 17 2015 13:48:48 GMT+0100 (Romance Standard Time)

module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: './',


    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],


    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
      'bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
      'bower_components/angular/angular.js',
      'bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js',
      'bower_components/angular-aria/angular-aria.js',
      'bower_components/angular-material/angular-material.js',
      'bower_components/angular-messages/angular-messages.js',
      'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
      'bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js',
      'bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js',
      'bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js',
      'bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap.js',
      'bower_components/ui-select/dist/select.js',
      'bower_components/angular-smart-table/dist/smart-table.js',
      'bower_components/angular-ui-switch/angular-ui-switch.js',
      'bower_components/angular-growl-v2/build/angular-growl.js',
      'bower_components/angular-number-picker/angular-number-picker.js',
      'bower_components/moment/moment.js',
      'app/*.js',
      'app/**/*.js',
      'tests/*.js'
    ],


    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [
    ],


    // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
    // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
    preprocessors: {
    },


    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
    // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
    reporters: ['progress'],


    // web server port
    port: 9876,


    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,


    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: true,


    // start these browsers
    // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
    browsers: ['Chrome'],

    plugins: [
      'karma-jasmine',
      'karma-chrome-launcher',
      'karma-firefox-launcher'
    ],

    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: false,

    // Concurrency level
    // how many browser should be started simultanous
    concurrency: Infinity
  })
};
```

So far, I'm getthing this error : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OyqWdE

Answer (score 1):

Just try to inject each factory by its own name :

```
describe("Services test", function () {
  var users, $httpBackend;

  beforeEach(function(){
    angular.mock.module('balrogApp.services');
    angular.mock.inject(function (_Users_, _$httpBackend_) {
      users        = _Users_;
      $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
    });
  });

  // clear all outstanding requests after each tests
  afterEach(function() {
    $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
    $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
  });

  it("Factories must be defined", function () {
    // simulate API response
    $httpBackend.when('/api/catalog/users/1337')
      .respond( 200, { id : 1337, name : 'Tom' } );

    // there is a better way to do it actually but I'm unable to make it work
    // $httpBackend.whenRoute('GET', '/api/catalog/users/:id')
    //     .respond(function ( method, url, data, headers, params ) {
    //         return [ 200, { user : params.id } ] ;
    //     });

    // make the user request to the API
    var user = users.get({id:1337});
    $httpBackend.flush();

    // test API returned Object
    expect(user.id).toBe(1337);
    expect(user.name).toBe('Tom');
  });
});
```

Let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: I'm getting the error `Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: requestsProvider <- requests` I suppose, I'll get the same error for `projects` and `users` after fixing this one. I think there is some dependancy missing ?
Also, how could I check if it has the correct value instead of just check if it is defined ?

Comment: have you included `angular-mocks` in your karma config file list and all the JS files needed to properly launch your application with all your dependencies like `thebalrogApp.config` module?

Comment: also check if `angular-resource` is included in the karma config file list.

Comment: Afaik, I got everything needed included, some using the `'app/*.js', 'app/**/*.js',` notation. You can see the complete error here : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OyqWdE

Comment: It might be because files are not included in the right order using the `*` notation, gonna investigate this direction

Comment: According to your logs, the `Requests` factory is not able to load the `$resource` provider. I'm looking into it to find a solution, can you add you karma config file in the question ? Thx

Comment: Question edited, my karma.conf.js should include all used js files

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95448/discussion-between-freezystem-and-ellone).

Comment: Oh, unfortunatly the chat seems to be blocked from where I am, I might join it only later when going back home

Comment: Still got the same unknown provider error (I also setted requests and projects). However I prefer to keep the _ notation for the function parameters. And for the better way to do it, I think it's because you need $routeParams in order to make it work.

Comment: Ok I know why : `angular.module('balrogApp.services', ['balrogApp.config', 'ngRoute'])` you forgot to include the `'ngRoute'` dependency. Let me know if its help

Comment: U mean `ngResource` right ? Thanks, it seems to be it, now I'm getting `ReferenceError: _$httpBackend_ is not defined`. I guess I need to add some dependancy in my test file for my `angular.mock.module("balrogApp.services")` as well ?

Comment: Yeah I mean `ngResource` sorry. `$httpBackend` is from `ngMock` module. You're not forced to use it. In my examples it allows your tests to fake a server response. Tell me if everything is ok now.

Comment: OK, I think there is one last thing missing causing this : `Error: Unexpected request: GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/catalog/users/1337
        No more request expected` Somehow I need to tell that I'm supposed to make this request somewhere ?

Comment: Try to replace the URL in `$httpBackend` like that `$httpBackend.when('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/catalog/users/1337')`

Comment: That's not it , the same error is thrown, the url was correct imo. Maybe it's because my app is making more than just one request, and I need to test them all ? But I don't think so, since the response is simulated anyway

Comment: you may try the `$httpBackend.whenRoute()` function to solve this bug. It was not working for me but it's in the official documentation. IMO this is a different question you may create a different thread to ask about it.

Comment: Actually the error `$digest already in progress` is also thrown : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OyqWdE
Not sure it changes anything

Comment: I will focus on a few other things for a bit and then will post another question like suggested if I didn't figure it out. Also this might be something to explore : http://neverfriday.com/2014/07/28/angularjs-testing-services-that-use-resource/
In any case, thanks a lot for your help and your patience.